Kubectl not in path with Azure Power Shell
I want to connect to a Kubernetes Cluster in Azure from a Windows Machine in the same Network.
I want to use the Azure Power Shell Module because of reasons.
I installed kubectl and kubelogin via Install-AzAksCliTool and the tools are in respective directories, e.g., C:\Users\USERNAME\.azure-kubectl
Then I run
Connect-AzAccount
Import-AzAksCredential -ResourceGroupName rgName -Name cName

however, independent of above calls, I cannot call kubectl or kubelogin:
kubelogin : The term 'kubelogin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I would suppose that Install-AzAksCliTool would automatically add these programes to the path. Is there any call I am missing?
Thanks

The default path will be "~/bin" Could you try the below command?
Install-AzAksCliTool -KubectlInstallVersion "v1.25.0" -KubectlInstallDestination "~/bin/" -KubeloginInstallVersion "v0.0.20" -KubeloginInstallDestination "~/bin"


~/bin is the path in Linux. I am using Windows.
